# STM8 UART Transmiission gets truncated

Tags: c, c-strings, stm8

I am using the stm8l151... mcu and I am trying to send different strings via Uart1 to HTerminal. I have three different strings to send. The first two strings are transmitted completely but when the third one is being sent, it is truncated and it starts to send the first and second string again and repeatedly but when i go step by step through the code then it works perfectly fine. But if i allow the code to run, then the problem occurs.

I have attached the output from Hterm (**uart_com**) for better understanding and also some parts of my code(**uart transmit and uart_init**)

Just for better understanding of the attached output, the strings(cmd 1, 2 and 3) are **at+nrb**, **at+cfun=1**, and **at+cops=1,2,"26201"**

Please, Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

```
void nbiot_buf_transmit(void){


  for(int i=0 ; i < sizeof(cmd1);i++){


    USART_SendData8(USART1,((uint8_t)cmd1[i]));
   while(!(USART1->SR));
     while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1,USART_FLAG_TXE)==RESET);

   }


   for(int i=0 ; i < sizeof(cmd2);i++){


    USART_SendData8(USART1,((uint8_t)cmd2[i]));
       while(!(USART1->SR));
     while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1,USART_FLAG_TXE)==RESET);

     }


   for(int i=0 ; i < sizeof(cmd3);i++){


    USART_SendData8(USART1,((uint8_t)cmd3[i]));
        while(!(USART1->SR));
     while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1,USART_FLAG_TXE)==RESET);

     }




void uart_init(void){
  /* init Tx and Rx Pins */
  GPIO_Init(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_Mode_Out_PP_High_Fast); //tx pin output
  GPIO_Init(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_2, GPIO_Mode_In_FL_No_IT);     //rx pin input
  /* enable usart1 clk */
  (CLK->PCKENR1 |= (uint8_t)((uint8_t)1 << ((uint8_t)CLK_Peripheral_USART1 & 
 (uint8_t)0x0F)));
  /* config for GPIO mode */
(CLK->PCKENR2 |= (uint8_t)((uint8_t)1 << ((uint8_t)CLK_Peripheral_COMP & 
(uint8_t)0x0F)));  
(RI->IOCMR3 &= 0xFD);
(RI->IOSR3 &= (uint8_t) (~(uint8_t) ((uint8_t)1 << (uint8_t) (RI_IOSwitch_6 
& (uint8_t) 0x0F)))); 

(CLK->PCKENR2 &= (uint8_t)(~(uint8_t)(((uint8_t)1 << 
((uint8_t)CLK_Peripheral_COMP & (uint8_t)0x0F)))));

  /* init usart peripheral */
  USART_Init(USART1,
         (PAL_dwCLK_FREQ_VALUE/9600),
         USART_WordLength_8b,
         USART_StopBits_1,
         USART_Parity_No,
         USART_Mode_Rx); //Rx enable
  ITC->ISPR8 &= 0xFC; // Set USART1_RX_IRQn on ITC_PriorityLevel_2
  ITC->ISPR7 &= 0x3F; // Set USART1_TX_IRQn on ITC_PriorityLevel_2
  /* enable usart1 peripheral */
 USART_Cmd(USART1,ENABLE)
 }
```

[image]

[strings definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxYN6.jpg)

Comment: Please show the definition of `cmd1` to `cmd3`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie done. added as attachement. They were defined globally

Comment: Note that with your `i< sizeof(cmd)` in the `for` loop you will also send the terminating null character. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes that is what i want

Comment: i forgot to add in the explanation of my problem that when i go step by step, there is no problem but when i allow the program to run, then the problem occurs.

Comment: So you probably have undefined behaviour somewhere. Also, that code is very poorly formatted.

Comment: @underscore_d   Yes, but i dont know where. I think it has something to do with the UART sending register. It somehow stores what has been sent before and when it gets to a certain length it stops and keeps repeatng what has been sent so far. I tried it with different strings and its the same thing. I guess there is nothing like clearing the register or?                                                                 And yes, am so sorry for the poor indentation.

Comment: are you calling this function in an Interrupt?